# ML variables in functions

Tags: function, variables, helper, sml, ml

I can't seem to find a simple answer to this seemingly simple SML question. I have the code:

```
    fun inde(x, y, L) = if null L then nil else
    if x=hd(L) then y+1::inde(x,y+1,tl L) else
    inde(x,y+1,tl L);
```

I want y to be a variable outside the function, so it'll be inde(x,L) but have the y still count properly. When I declare it outside the function (to 0), when the function is recursively called, it resets to 0.

If you were to run this current function, it'd produce a list of where ever x is in the list (L).
so inde(1,0,[1,2,2,1,1]) would produce [1,4,5]

Comment: Variables in Standard ML are actual mathematical variables, whose meaning is given by substitution, not by a series of reassignments. [Source](http://existentialtype.wordpress.com/2012/02/01/words-matter/). An immediate consequence of this is that you cannot modify the value a variable stands for in a given context.

Answer (score 1):

Idiomatic structure when using a functional programming style is to define an inner function that takes arguments that are of interest to the programmer, but not the user and then to call the inner function from the main function:

```
fun inde(x : int, L) =
  let
    fun inner(list1, list2, y : int) =
      if null list1 
      then List.rev list2 
      else
        if x = hd list1
        then
          inner(tl list1, y::list2, y + 1)
        else
          inner(tl list1, list2, y +1)
    in
      inner(L,[],1)
    end
```

In the example function:

- `inner` uses four values: the local variables `list1`,`list2`, and `y`. It also uses `x` from the enclosing scope.
- `inner` builds (conses up) the list that will be returned using `list2`. It reverses the list with a call to `List.rev` from the [SML Basis Library](http://sml-family.org/Basis/list.html#SIG:LIST.app:VAL:SPEC). This adds O(n) to the execution time.
- The last part of the `let...in...end` construct: `inner(L,[],1)` is called "the trampoline" because the code gets all the way to the bottom of the source file and then bounces off it to start execution. It's a standard pattern.
- Note that I started iterating with `y` equal to 1, rather than 0. Starting at zero wasn't getting anything done in the original file.

Comment: What is the naming convention for `inner`? I tend to use `fun bla ... let fun bla_ ... in bla_ ...` I think there was a better way because this is Python influence, clearly, and I programmed in ML before I did in Python.

Comment: @rudolfovic I named the function 'inner' because my answer illustrated the use of inner functions [see my answer's non-code text]. Naming is one of Martin Fowler's two hard problems in computer science. I'm not saying that 'inner' is a good name, but two years later, I can read my code and explain why I named the inner function 'inner'...and why I named the outer function 'inde'. So if there's a convention, it's programs primarily written for humans to read. Good luck.